# How to combine these two arrays when array_combine is not the solution?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with name `$name[]` and another one with the name `$content[]` Both arrays have equal objects ( 3 ). The `$content[]` array may have 0, 1 or 2 messages as seen below.

My aim is to echo the `$name[0]` with the `$content[0]` and so on. The name will be printed first and after the available messages. I tried to use `array_combine` without luck.

What is a way to do this?

*$name[]*

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

*$content[]*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [message] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [message] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [message] => 
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: You've left out one key detail: what the combined array should look like. From what you've described, `array_combine` should be the solution. What should be the result of combining the sample arrays? What about the result of `array_combine` isn't appropriate? The output of `var_export` is more useful than `var_dump` for sample data, as it produces valid PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really no idea what you're trying to do; the question isn't very clear. What's your expected output?

Here's my stab in the dark:

```
$count = min(count($name),count($content));

for($i=0; $i<$count; ++$i) {
    echo $name[$i];
    foreach($content[$i] as $msg) {
        echo $msg['message'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark for it. It works as I want it with a little tweak.

Comment: Alternative solution for PHP 5.3+ with `MultipleIterator`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14724544/664108

Answer (score 1):

Like so?

```
$name = array(...);
$content = array(...);

foreach( $content as $k => $v )
{
  if( array_key_exists( $k, $name ) )
    echo $name[$k];

  if( array_key_exists( $k, $content ) )
    echo $content[$k];
}
```

Comment: What I get is the name and after *Array*.

Comment: @Kaoukkos: That's because $content is an array of arrays. Just loop over it.